# Upgrading MvvmCross to 5.2 shows error on CustomAndroidPresenter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

After upgrading MvvmCross from 5.1 to 5.2 , my CustomAndroidPresenter.cs is throwing a build error. What is causing this?

CustomAndroidPresenter.cs:

```
namespace TestPrjDroid
{
    public class CustomAndroidPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
    {
        public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            if (request != null && request.PresentationValues != null)
            {
                if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("MyCustomFlag"))
                {
                    // Get intent from request and set flags to clear backstack.
                    var intent = base.CreateIntentForRequest(request);
                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    base.Show(intent);
                    return;
                }
            }
            base.Show(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'androidViewAssemblies' of
>   'MvxAndroidViewPresenter.MvxAndroidViewPresenter(IEnumerable)'
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.Content.Intent' to
>   'MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest'

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a constructor for `MvxAndroidViewPresenter(IEnumerable)`:

```
public class CustomAndroidPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
{

    public CustomAndroidPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies) : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (request != null && request.PresentationValues != null)
        {
            if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("MyCustomFlag"))
            {
                // Get intent from request and set flags to clear backstack.
                var intent = base.CreateIntentForRequest(request);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                base.ShowIntent(intent);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.Show(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws: 
Error CS0246: `The type or namespace name 'Assembly' could not be found`

Comment: @Mukteswar Patnaik, try using `System.Reflection.Assembly`.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT    
I tried that too, it throws the following errors.

Error CS7036 `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'androidViewAssemblies' of 'CustomAndroidPresenter.CustomAndroidPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly>)'`

Error CS1503 `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.Content.Intent' to 'MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest'`

Comment: @Mukteswar Patnaik , in your `Setup.cs`class, add a parameter when you initialize your `CustomAndroidPresenter` like this : `var presenter = new CustomAndroidPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies)`, for another error, 
 please using `base.ShowIntent(intent)` instead of `base.Show(intent)`.